# Implementing a SpinLock in a HLSL DirectCompute shader

Tags: directx, hlsl, spinlock, directcompute

I try to implement a spin lock in a compute shader. But my implementation it doesn't seems to lock anything.

Here is how I implement the spin lock:

```
void LockAcquire()
{
    uint Value = 1;

    [allow_uav_condition]
    while (Value) {
        InterlockedCompareExchange(DataOutBuffer[0].Lock, 0, 1, Value);
    };
}

void LockRelease()
{
    uint Value;
    InterlockedExchange(DataOutBuffer[0].Lock, 0, Value);
}
```

Background: I need a spin lock because I have to compute a sum of data in a large 2 dimensions array. The sum is a double. Computing the sum with a single thread and a double loop produce the correct result. Computing the sum with multithreading produce the wrong result, even when introducing the spin lock to avoid conflict when computing the sum.

I can't use InterLockedAdd because the sum doesn't fit into a 32 bits integer and I'm using a shader model 5 (Compiler 47).

Here is the single thread version, producing the correct result:

```
[numthreads(1, 1, 1)]
void CSGrayAutoComputeSumSqr(
    uint3 Gid  : SV_GroupID,
    uint3 DTid : SV_DispatchThreadID, // Coordinates in RawImage window
    uint3 GTid : SV_GroupThreadID,
    uint  GI   : SV_GroupIndex)
{
    if ((DTid.x == 0) && (DTid.y == 0)) {
        uint2 XY;
        int   Mean = (int)round(DataOutBuffer[0].GrayAutoResultMean);
        for (XY.x = 0; XY.x < (uint)RawImageSize.x; XY.x++) {
            for (XY.y = 0; XY.y < (uint)RawImageSize.y; XY.y++) {
                int  Value  = GetPixel16BitGrayFromRawImage(RawImage, rawImageSize, XY);
                uint UValue = (Mean - Value) * (Mean - Value);
                DataOutBuffer[0].GrayAutoResultSumSqr += UValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and below is the multithreaded version. This version produce similar but different result on each execution which IMO is caused by the not functioning lock.

```
[numthreads(1, 1, 1)]
void CSGrayAutoComputeSumSqr(
    uint3 Gid  : SV_GroupID,
    uint3 DTid : SV_DispatchThreadID, // Coordinates in RawImage window
    uint3 GTid : SV_GroupThreadID,
    uint  GI   : SV_GroupIndex)
{
    int  Value  = GetPixel16BitGrayFromRawImage(RawImage, RawImageSize, DTid.xy);
    int  Mean   = (int)round(DataOutBuffer[0].GrayAutoResultMean);
    uint UValue = (Mean - Value) * (Mean - Value);
    LockAcquire();
    DataOutBuffer[0].GrayAutoResultSumSqr += UValue;
    LockRelease();
}
```

Data used:

```
cbuffer TImageParams : register(b0)
{
    int2   RawImageSize;       // Actual image size in RawImage
}

struct TDataOutBuffer
{
    uint   Lock;                             // Use for SpinLock
    double GrayAutoResultMean;
    double GrayAutoResultSumSqr;
};

ByteAddressBuffer                  RawImage       : register(t0);
RWStructuredBuffer<TDataOutBuffer> DataOutBuffer  : register(u4);
```

Dispatch code:

```
FImmediateContext->CSSetShader(FComputeShaderGrayAutoComputeSumSqr, NULL, 0);
FImmediateContext->Dispatch(FImageParams.RawImageSize.X, FImageParams.RawImageSize.Y, 1);
```

The function GetPixel16BitGrayFromRawImage access RawImage byte address buffer to fetch 16 bit pixel value from a gray scale image. It produce the expected result.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried locking above this line: int  Mean   = (int)round(DataOutBuffer[0].GrayAutoResultMean); or even above int  Value  = GetPixel16BitGrayFromRawImage(RawImage, RawImageSize, DTid.xy);

Comment: No, I have not tried because it is a non-sense. Anyway, I just tried right now and this doesn't change. BTW: GetPixel16BitGrayFromRawImage is thread safe because it only access readonly data and it is proved because I heavily use it in many other multithreaded places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are victim of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here.

Let's start with the Y problem.
**Your spin lock does not lock.**
To understand why  you spin lock does not work, you need to examine how a GPU handles the situation you are creating. You issue a warp, made of one or more thread-groups, each of which made by many threads. The execution of the warp is fast as long as the execution is parallel, that means that all the threads that make a warp (wavefront if you prefer), must execute *the same instruction* at *the same time*. Every time you insert a condition (like the `while` loop in your algo), some of your threads must take a route, and some the other. This is called *divergence* of the threads. The problem is that you cannot execute *different instructions* in parallel.

In this case the GPU can take one of two routes:

1. *Dynamic branching* which means that the wavefront (the warp) takes one of the 2 routes, and deactivates the threads that should take the other. Then, it rolls back to pick up the sleeping threads where they were left.
2. *Flat branching* which means that all threads execute both branches, then each thread discards the unwanted result and keeps the correct one.

Now the funny part:

**There is no cast rule stating how a GPU is supposed to handle branching.**

You have no way to predict whether the GPU will use one approach or the other, and in case of dynamic branching there is no way to know in advance if the GPU will put to sleep the straight route, the other, the branch with less threads or the one with more. There is no way to know in advance, and different GPUs might execute the code differently (and will). The same GPU might even change its execution with different driver versions.

In case of your spinlock, your GPU (and its driver, and the compiler version you are currently using) most probably go for the flat branching strategy. This means that both branches are executed by all threads of a warp, so there basically is no lock at all.

If you change the code (or add the `[branch]` attribute before the loop) you can force the dynamic branching flow. But this would not solve your issues. In the particular case of a spinlock, what you are asking the GPU to do is to shut off *all threads but one*. And this is not exactly what the GPU will want to do. The GPU will try to do the opposite, and shut the only thread that evaluates the condition differently. This will indeed lead to less *divergence* and increase performance…but in your case it will shut off *the only thread that is not in an endless loop*. So, you might get a full wavefront of threads locked in an endless loop, because the only one that might unlock the loop...is sleeping. Your **spinlock** has effectively become a **deadlock**.

Now, in your particular machine, the program might even run fine. But you have exactly **zero guarantees** that the program will run on other machines, or even with different driver versions. You update the driver and boom, you program suddenly hits a GPU Timeout and crashes.

The best suggestion about spinlocks in GPUs is….don't use them. Ever.

Now let's get back to you **Y problem**.

What you really need is a way to *compute a sum of data in a large 2 dimensions array*.
So what you are really looking for is a good *reduction algorithm*. There are some on the internet, or you can code your own, depending on your needs.

I will just add a few links to get you started, if you need them.

[A Digression on Divergence](https://tangentvector.wordpress.com/2013/04/12/a-digression-on-divergence/)

[NVIDIA - GPU Technology Conference 2010 Slides](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2010/presentations/S12312-DirectCompute-Pre-Conference-Tutorial.pdf)

[Goddeke - Introductory tutorial](https://www.mathematik.uni-dortmund.de/~goeddeke/gpgpu/tutorial2.html)

[Donovan - GPU Parallel Scan](http://users.umiacs.umd.edu/~ramani/cmsc828e_gpusci/ScanTalk.pdf)

[Barlas - Multicore and GPU programming](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/reduction-algorithm)

Comment: Waouw! I think I have to learn a lot before going on. Thanks for your help. Thanks for the references.

Comment: If I may give you a suggestion that you did not ask for ;) I see you always dispatch threadgroups with a single thread [numthreads(1, 1, 1)]. This is very inefficient. A good starting base might be threadgroups with 64, 128 or 256 threads. Then you can optimize further.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will enter a new question so that we can properly discuss this topic.

Comment: I followed your suggestion: now I use a large number of threads per group and performance is an order of magnitude higher. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I'll answer it ASAP, but it's not an easy matter so I have to have some time to give a good answer. BTW, if these answers helped you, consider accepting them if you find them satisfactory.

Comment: @kefren you wrote "You issue a warp, made of one or more thread-groups". I think you meant the opposite: You issue a dispatch call of several threadgroups containing each numthread threads (you decide these numbers) ; each threadgroup will run on one or several warps/wavefronts (their size is fixed by the GPU)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by kefren, your spinlock does not work because of warp divergence. However there is a way to design a gpu spinlock that does not result in a deadlock. I used this spinlock for a pixel shader but it should also work in a compute shader.

```
RWTexture2D<uint> mutex; // all values are 0 in the beginning

void doCriticalPart(int2 coord) {
   bool keepWaiting = true;
   while(keepWaiting) {
      uint originalValue;
      // try to set the mutex to 1
      InterlockedCompareExchange(mutex[coord], 0, 1, originalValue);
      if(originalValue == 0) { // nothing was locked (previous entry was 0)
         // do your stuff
         // unlock mutex again
         InterlockedExchange(mutex[coord], 0, originalValue);
         // exit loop
         keepWaiting = false;
      }
   }
}
```

There is a detailed explanation on why this works in my [Bachelor Thesis](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332371662_Order-Independent_Transparency_Acceleration) on page 30. There is also an example for GLSL.

Note: If you want to use this spinlock in a pixel shader, you have to check for `SV_SampleIndex == 0` before calling this function. The pixel shader may spawn some helper invocations to determine texture fetch mipmap levels which cause undefined behaviour for atomic operations. This could result in an infinite execution of the loop for those helper invocation, resulting in a deadlock

Comment: Your implementation is not really different than mine except you wrote the code inline and I used function. As HLSL compiler inline all function, this become almost the same.

Comment: The difference is that in my implementation the while loop is around the `LockAcquire` AND `LockRelease`. Your while loop is only around the `LockAcquire` which may cause a deadlock because all threads in a group only advance as a group (lockstep) => If even a single thread does not get the lock in your implementation, all other threads won't advance and therefore won't release their lock

Comment: fpiette's implementation did non result in a deadlock, in his hardware. It *might* on some hardware. On his hardware, the problem was that both branches were executed for all threads, and this resulted in *no lock* at all. The same might happen on your implementation, and the fact that it works on your particular hardware/driver pair, does not give any guarantee for other hardware or other driver versions. You *can* obtain a spinlock that works on your PC. But you cannot make, in GPUs, a spinlock that works reliably on every hardware revisions or on all driver versions.

Comment: What happens if I add the [branch] tag before the if statement. Then the inside would only be executed if the lock was actually acquired. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Your mutex is broken because there is no guarantee that the following won't happen:

1. Thread A acquires the lock
2. Warp always executes the 'failed to acquire lock' branch indefinitely, planning to execute A after that (but that'll never happen)
3. Thread A never resumes execution, thus never releases the mutex